# Task scheduler : how to launch a batchfile or program every minute

Tags: windows-10, command-line, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2016

I'd like to launch a batchfile, every minute.

In order to do this, I wanted to create the task using standard task scheduler, and in case this fails, use the `schtasks` commandline.

So first I tried using standard task scheduler:
Create the task,
have "Daily" as a trigger,
details (At 9:20 every day),
status "Enabled".

The action is "Start a program", being "C:...\Tester.bat" (this batchfile exists).
Now that I have created it, I can modify it in order to be more specific, but this does not work:

I ask for the properties, I click on "OK" (without touching anything) and I get the error message:

> An error has occurred for task Tester. Error message: One or more of the specified arguments are not valid.

How is this even possible? I create something, following its own wizard, and there might something wrong? And even if I did something wrong, how can I know what I did wrong?

When I ask `Schtasks /Query /TN Tester`, I get following results:

```
Folder: \
TaskName         Next Run Time   Status
=========== ================== ========
     Tester 29/03/2019 9:20:00    Ready
```

That's all? What about the other parameters (trigger, advanced trigger, action,  ...)?

About creating a task, using `schtasks`, that's also not very clear:

In order to create a task, which is run every minute, one mentions the usage of `/MO` switch as a modifier for the schedule recurrence, but while editing the `schtasks /Change /?` the `/MO` switch seems not to be there.

In order to make things completely complicated: I'm working here on a Windows-10 machine, and the task itself needs to be configured on a customer's PC, which is Windows-Server 2016, hence I would like to have a robust way of working, which I can easily explain to my customer.

**Edit after first comment**

This is the result of `schtasks`, using the `/V` switch (I still don't see what might be wrong):

```
Prompt>schtasks /Query /TN Tester /V

Folder: \
HostName      TaskName   Next Run Time        Status   Logon Mode         Last Run Time         Last Result Author           Task To Run                 Start In          Comment   Scheduled Task State   Idle Time   Power Management                              Run As User   Delete Task If Not Rescheduled Stop Task If Runs X Hours and X Mins     Schedule                                           Schedule Type   Start Time   Start Date End Date   Days             Months   Repeat: Every   Repeat: Until: Time  Repeat: Until: Duration   Repeat: Stop If Still Running
============= ========== ==================== ======== ================== ==================== ============ ================ =========================== ================= ========= ====================== =========== ============================================= ============= ============================== ======================================== ================================================== =============== ============ ========== ========== ================ ======== =============== ==================== ========================= =============================
DOMINIQUEDS   Tester     29/03/2019 9:20:00   Ready    Interactive only   28/03/2019 9:20:00    -1073741510 SKYLINE2\Dominiq C:\Temp_Folder\Tester.bat   C:\Temp_Folder\   N/A       Enabled                Disabled    Stop On Battery Mode, No Start On Batteries   DominiqueDS   Disabled                       72:00:00                                 Scheduling data is not available in this format.   Daily           9:20:00      28/03/2019 N/A        Every 1 day(s)   N/A      Disabled        Disabled             Disabled                  Disabled
```

Does anybody know how to get this done?
Thanks in advance

Comment: As for the "what about other parameters?" part of your question, you can add the `/V` switch to the `SchTasks /Query /TN Tester` command to get the verbose details. That might help discover if there is perhaps a typo in the "Task To Run" field.

Comment: @Dominique . . . are you just having trouble getting a batch file to run with Task Scheduler every 1 minute forever creating it from the Task Scheduler graphical interface or are you trying to run `schtasks` commands to create it. I'm very familiar with Task Scheduler and have done this many times so I can help but I need to better understand if you simple need to create it via the Task Scheduler GUI or having trouble with a command? Are you fine with just a GUI solution from Task Scheduler with no command line if it work? I think I can help but will wait to hear back.